# Controlling user date picking based on two different values

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I have this case:

two datepickers,and two values, and a select (HTML terms).

```
Select Start
<input type="date" name ="datepicker_start" id="datepicker" value=""  class="datepicker" size="20" />
<br>
Select End
<input type="date" name ="datepicker_end" id="datepicker2"  value="" class="datepicker" size="20" />
<br>
Balance 1
<input type="number" name="tleave" id="Total" value="20" readonly="true" size="10" />
<br>
Balance 2
<input type="number" name="tleave2" id="Total2" value="2" readonly="true" size="10" />
<br>
<select onchange="checkdate();" name="LeaveType">
    <option value="0"> select balance</option>
    <option value="1"> Balance 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Balance 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Balance 3</option>
</select>
```

I started putting up a code that checks the input dates and compare it to a value depending on the selection of select option.

```
function checkdate() {

    var start = new Date( $('#datepicker').val() ).getTime(),
        end = new Date( $('#datepicker2').val() ).getTime();
        diff = ((end - start) / 86400000) ;
        //1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 1 day = 86400000
    if ($('#element option[value="1"]').attr("selected", "selected"))
    {
        if( diff > $('#Total').val())
        {
            alert( diff+ " days of balance 1 more than the available" );
        }
    }
    if ($('#element option[value="2"]').attr("selected", "selected"))
    {
        if( diff > $('#Total2').val())
        {
            alert( diff+ " days of balance 2 more than the available" );
        }
    }
};
```

I.E. let consider that the user have two different balances,so after he selects the duration,based on which balance type he wants,the function should returns a pop-up if the balance is less the requested.

the current issue is that : the function is not separating on changing option.(you will understand better if you check the code below)

or here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67NbU/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fixed it.
I added ID to the select

```
<select onchange="checkdate();" name="LeaveType" id="LeaveType">
```

the issue was on these lines :

```
if ($('#element option[value="1"]').attr("selected", "selected"))
```

and

```
if ($('#element option[value="2"]').attr("selected", "selected"))
```

i changed them to:

```
var option = document.getElementById("LeaveType").value;
if (option =='1')
```

AND

```
if (option =='2')
```

Now function is working great.
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You could make a shorter version of your code if you change the id of `#Total` to `#Total1` and use this:

```
function checkdate() {
    var start = new Date( $('#datepicker').val() ).getTime(),
        end = new Date( $('#datepicker2').val() ).getTime();
    var diff = ((end - start) / 86400000) ;
    var val = $('#LeaveType').val();
    if( diff > $('#Total'+val).val()){
        alert( diff+ " days of balance "+val+" more than the available" );
    }
};
```

Comment: For me it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/67NbU/1/) just make sure to change the id I mentioned